# Excel VBA run-time error 1004 : Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA and writing a macro trying to loop for all excel files in a specific user selected directory and I want to copy its content (which are tables in each excel file), but this error occurs when It's run the code and open the first excel file "Excel VBA run-time error 1004 : Application-defined or object-defined error". I didn't know what is the problem with it.

Here is the code

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
        
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

 Range("A1").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.Copy
 
 
    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
      
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to qualify what context the `Range("A1").Select` etc. applies to. You have opened a workbook, but Excel does not know where the range is that you want to select. It could be in a different universe, because you never tell Excel that it is in the file you just opened.

To use a range in any workbook, you need to qualify it with the workbook and the worksheet. In some situations that is not required, because there is only one possible context, but here the code fails without these pointers. Try along these lines:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
        
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

 Dim ws as worksheet
 set ws = wb.Sheets(1) ' or however you want to identify which sheet to use
```

Now you can use `ws.Range()` to address a range in the specified sheet.
You may also want to read up about how to avoid "Select" when manipulating Excel cells. There are many ways to replace your Select statements, for example the following code will replace the four lines you used to copy the populated range from A1 to the right and down.

```
ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
```

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: All good advice, _except_ you should have gone on and removed the reliance on Select/Selection.  As posted your code will fail if Sheet(1) in the newly opened wb isn't active.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I didn't want this to cauliflower into a full tutorial, but you're right. I've posted a better line of code.